# Pass parent resolver arguments in child resolver

Tags: go, graphql, graphql-go

I have a nested GraphQL query with the following structure

```
    query{
                
    parentMetrics(cityNames: ["Cali"], orderingDateFrom: "2021-01-01"){
            sales
            orders
            childMetrics(cityNames: ["Cali"], orderingDateFrom: "2021-01-01"){
                aov
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I am repeating the arguments because in the backend we run different queries to get *parentMetrics* and *childMetrices* but they require the same set of args which is redundant.

Can I do something like this instead?

```
query{
            
parentMetrics(cityNames: ["Cali"], orderingDateFrom: "2021-01-01"){
        sales
        orders
        childMetrics{
            aov
        }
    }
}
```

I am using **github.com/graphql-go/graphql** and currently this is what my code looks like

```
 "parentMetrics": &graphql.Field{
                            Type:    partnerGQL.ParentMetrics,
                            Args:    graphql.FieldConfigArgument{
                                             "cityNames": &graphql.ArgumentConfig{
                                             Type:graphql.NewList(graphql.String),
                                             }
                                             "orderingDateFrom":&graphql.ArgumentConfig{
                            Type: graphql.String,
    }
        },
                            Resolve: partnerResolver.ResolveOrderItemMetrics,
}
```

The *parentMetric*s type has the nested Resolver for *childMetrics*

Answer (score 0):

When you return a parent metric object, include the arguments of `parentMetrics` call in that object.

The resolver for `childMetrics` will get the parent object and will be able to read its arguments from there.

A quick example in Javascript:

```
const resolvers = {
  parentMetrics: (parent, args) => {
    const metric = getParentMetric(args);
    return {
      ...metric,
      args: args,
    };
  },
  childMetrics: (parent) => {
    return getChildMetric(parent.args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a code example? hard to understand, I can provide more sample code if needed from my end

Comment: I added a small example in Javascript, as I don't know go.